# How to configure router/server to make users from wired and wireless connection see each other?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-server-2008, wired-networking

How can I make users from wired network see users from wireless connection?

The wired network subnet is 10.0.2.0/24. The router for wireless connection has 10.0.2.100 IP and wireless network is under 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.

The problem is that while connected to wifi I can ping adresses from wired network, but I can't see the users connected to wired network in windows networking - and I need it to access Windows Active Directory.

Many thanks for any suggestions how to solve this problem

Comment: Why not make the wireless or wired network on 192.168.0.0/23 or 10.0.0.0/23 and put the wireless on x.x.1.x and wired on x.x.0.x?

Comment: Also if you can't change subnet for either network, you'll need to put static routes for those two network to make this work.

Comment: Ensure Wireless isolation is turned off (if the router supports it).

Answer (score 0):

You want to turn off NAT in the router and instead have it act like only an access point and not a router. This way, a user connecting to the wireless access point will be on the 192.168.1.x network and will get an IP address from the DHCP server on that network.

The exact settings to do this depend on the router make/model.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no turning NAT feature off in my router (TL-WR940N) I've tried to turn off DHCP, and assign IP to my computer manually, but it never works. I also tried to assign same subnet as LAN on the router, but when I try to accept the settings, alert appears, which says that LAN can't be in the same subnet as WAN adress.